# Find and remove specific string from a line

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

I am hoping to receive some feedback on some code I have written in Python 3 - I am attempting to write a program that reads an input file which has page numbers in it. The page numbers are formatted as: "[13]" (this means you are on page 13). My code right now is:

```
pattern='\[\d\]'

for line in f:
if pattern in line:
    re.sub('\[\d\]',' ')
    re.compile(line)
    output.write(line.replace('\[\d\]', ''))
```

I have also tried:

```
for line in f:
    if pattern in line:
    re.replace('\[\d\]','')
    re.compile(line)
    output_file.write(line)
```

When I run these programs, a blank file is created, rather than a file containing the original text minus the page numbers. Thank you in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Your if statement won't work because not doing a regex match, it's looking for the literal string `\[\d\]` in `line`.

```
for line in f:
    # determine if the pattern is found in the line
    if re.match(r'\[\d\]', line):
        subbed_line = re.sub(r'\[\d\]',' ')
        output_file.writeline(subbed_line)
```

Additionally, you're using the `re.compile()` incorrectly. The purpose of it is to pre-compile your pattern into a function. This improves performance if you use the pattern a lot because you only evaluate the expression once, rather than re-evaluating each time you loop.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\[\d\]')

if pattern.match(line):
    # ...
```

Lastly, you're getting a blank file because you're using `output_file.write()` which writes a string as the entire file. Instead, you want to use `output_file.writeline()` to write lines to the file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't write unmodified lines to your output.

Try something like this

```
if pattern in line:
    #remove page number stuff
output_file.write(line) # note that it's not part of the if block above
```

That's why your output file is empty.